# Android fragments communication with maps

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary, interface

I have in my project an activity (that extends FragmentActivity), and two fragments (extends v4.fragment and one of them has a map fragment).

I made my project for tablet, and both fragments are shown on screen.
the problem is, I tried communicating between them (adding a marker on map from another fragment) , by using an Interface that is implemented in the activity.,
and for some reason my googleMap object returns null.

when I'm trying to use method inside the fragment
(e.g: options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)) using my googleMap object 
it's working.
any idea what did i do wrong?

Comment: Post the code you have for communicating between those two fragments.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. rookie mistake-  I did'nt call the right fragment id from xml....  ( :